# Change from Outlook.com back to Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com

I had a Hotmail account but it changed to Outlook.com .

I really want my Hotmail settings back - anyone know how I can make my Outlook.com account change back to my Hotmail one?

I still have the Hotmail email address but not the Hotmail format.